# How do you prevent a new-line feed at the end of a Silverlight wrappanel

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, wrappanel

Is it possible to stop a Silverlight wrappanel from forcing all content after it onto a new line.

The problem is this: I have an Items collection, and immediately after it, I would like a text box.
You can imagine it like an email "To:" field, it appears like a text area with bubbles in it, and I want to allow the users to continue to add to the list immediately after the end of the last bubble, but alas the wrappanel forces a line-break.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add the items to the wrappanel to get it to continue the flow.